# Squid transparent proxy: bypass the dhcp server

Tags: proxy, dhcp, squid

I'm working on a simple network who consist in 4 ADSL connections managed by a ER5120 load balancer. The load balancer is connected to a switch who connects with the guys at the office.

Now, I'm going to install a computer between the load balancer and the switch. That computer runs Debian GNU/Linux and Squid to get some statistics about the traffic (most visited sites, most bandwidth-eater users, etc).

I want to bypass the dhcp server (who is installed in the load balancer) and I want the computer only for that kind of monitoring.

That is possible?

Is there any other way to do the monitoring I want?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Setup your Debian box as a [bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridging_%28networking%29).

Comment: And then intercept http traffic with iptables (or maybe ebtables, never tried this), pointing it at squid running in transparent proxy mode.